# An error in my understanding of entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Based on my knowledge of quantum entanglement, I can set up a scenario which leads to a contradiction with the No-communication theorem. Please help me find the flaw.

Suppose Alice wants to communicate a message to Bob (1 or 0). Alice has 100 electrons (which we will call a_1, a_2, ..., a_100) and Bob also has 100 electrons (which we will call b_1, b_2, ..., b_100). Each one of Alice's electrons is entangled to exactly one of Bob's electrons such that a_n and b_n have opposite spin. First, Alice measures the spin of each of her electrons along the z axis and records each result. Then, if Bob wants to communicate a zero, he does not measure the spin of his electron, so that when Alice measures her's a second time about the z axis, she gets the same results as in her first measurement. If Bob wants to communicate a 1, he measures the spin of each one of his electrons about the x axis so that when Alice makes a second measurement of each of her electrons about the z axis, her results should not be correlated to the first measurement she took. If everything I said were true, this would provide a very high probability for Bob to correctly transfer a bit of information to Alice, potentially at faster than light speeds which violates the No-communication theorem.

Comment: once Alice has measured her electrons the wavefunction collapses and the entanglement is broken, so Bob's measurements (or non-measurements) do not affect Alice's electrons anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once Alice makes the measurement, her state is collapsed and her spin will not be affected by Bob's subsequent measurement. Bob's spin is now determined in the z-direction, however, which is what allows the usual quantum key-distribution techniques.

To be more precise:

Before Alice's measurement the state is $$|+ \rangle |-\rangle - |-\rangle |+\rangle.$$

After, if Alice measures a positive spin, it is $$|+\rangle|-\rangle.$$

Then, Bob measures, but this only changes his spin: $$|+\rangle (|-\rangle + |+\rangle)$$

Alice's spin is not acted on.

Comment: Ok, but then it seems to me that entanglement just refers to our knowledge of how parts the a system relate to each other. How do we know that the particles' spins are not just corollated, but that the particles are actually in communication with each other?

Comment: That's a fascinating question, and ultimately I don't think I can give you an answer correctly. This forms the core of the "EPR paradox." Einstein believed there was a "hidden variable theory" (the spins are already determined even if we don't know them) that would prevent this famous "spooky action at a distance." The counter-argument is quite technical, but it can be shown that the correlations are unlike any correlations that would be seen in a hidden variable theory. This was proven in "Bell's theorem," although off the top of my head I can't think of any good nontechnical explanations.

Comment: @SamuelMontgomery:  We do not know that the particles are "in communication" with each other because they are *not* in communication with each other.  On the other hand, entanglement is certainly *not* just correlation, because the statistics of Alice and Bob's measurements violates Bell's Theorem.